# Select access to all tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In oracle 11g, I have a owner schema which contains the relevant tables required for an app.

For my external application i am trying to create another user which should have select access on certain tables to the above schema.
Lets call the owner schema A and the new schema B

```
  create user B identified by blah;
  grant connect to B;
```

After logging into the original schema A i ran the following (for demo i am giving select on all tables)

```
  begin
  FOR x IN (select * from user_tables)
  LOOP
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO some_role';
  END LOOP;
  end;

  grant some_role to B;
```

If i login as user B and execute a query like

```
  select count(*) from A.some_table ;
```

it works. But without creating a public synonym is it possible for me to grant 
in such a way that the following works when logged in as user B?

```
  select count(*) from some_table;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create private synonyms for user B to use.
As user B, run the following block:

```
begin
FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM role_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'SOME_ROLE' and owner = 'A')
LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREAETE SYNONYM ' || table_name || ' FOR A.' || table_name';
END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: when i run the above select as user B, i am getting empty rows.. even select * from user_tab_privs for user B gives empty rows

Comment: sorry i was doing it through roles...so select * from role_tab_privs works !!

Comment: @cableload thanks, didn't notice the role issue for some reason. I amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just *reading* data from tables owned by userB, you can set below command and run SELECT on tables as if they were in userA schema:

```
alter session set current_schema=userB
```

(logged as *UserA*)

Then below two commands will be equivalent (have same result):

```
select ... from userB.TABLE1

select ... from TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO YOUR_USER_OR_ROL;
```